# ReactTransitionGroup - wait for leave to finish before calling willComponentEnter on the incoming component

Tags: reactjs

`componentWillLeave` has a callback for when a component is done animating out

How can I have the component that's animating in to wait for the leave to finish before brining the incoming component in?

Comment: I could be wrong but could you not define a `transition-delay` in the CSS transition you want to apply in order to delay the _entering_ animation?

Comment: The problem with doing it that way is that it'll be fixed value for all components animating in in that transition group.  I wouldn't be able to have one component's animate in take 0.3 seconds, and anothers take 0.5 seconds

Comment: That is true. It definitely is a very fixed and rigid value. I will try to dig what else can be done.